# Making UIButton Wrap Following a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, uilabel

We have a multi-line text-wrapping UILabel with some text in it. At the end of the label we want to always place a UIButton as shown.

[image]

What's the simplest way to implement this? The text in the button must not break i.e. the button must flow on to the next line as a unit if there isn't enough space.

Comment: I would use`NSAttributedString` instead, it's a little easier to implement for this.

Comment: I would suggest it https://github.com/hsusmita/SwiftResponsiveLabel

Comment: thanks @the4kman, attributed string + non-breaking space does the trick.

Comment: thanks @SalmanGhumsani, looks useful.

Comment: @GauravSharma You can answer your own question too :) , if you think that it may be helpful to others :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an attributed string with non-breaking spaces ("\u{00a0}") works.